# VBA to throw a prompt when clicked on protected cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have Workbook with both Sheet/workbook is protected.
I have a code to lock/disable certain range of cells when the drop-down value "no" And unlock/enable when value of drop down is "yes"
Whereas, drop-down value and cells I would like to disable are on different sheets.

Dropdown on "Main Sheet"
Range of cells on "Sub Sheet"

I also need to throw a prompt to user when he clicks on protected range and when the value is set to "No".

I am using following code on "Main Sheet"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim worksh As Integer
Dim worksheetexists As Boolean
Dim str1 As String

If UCase$(Range("E30").Value) = "YES" Then
               Sheets("SubSheet").Select
               Sheets("SubSheet").Range("E20:I3019").Locked = False
               Sheets("SubSheet").Range("E20:I3019").Activate
           Else
                Sheets("SubSheet").Range("E20:I3019").Locked = True
End If
End Sub
```

Following code on Sub Sheet

```
Private Sub WorkBook_SheetChange(ByVal sh as Object, ByVal Target as Range)
If Intersect (Target, sh.Range("$E$19:$I$3000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
MsgBox "Please select the appropriate dropdown on MAIN Sheet " & Target.Address
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .UnDo
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Not sure, where am I going wrong as Its not throwing prompt when user clicks on protected cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. You should remove the `Sheets("SubSheet").Select`. If you running your code and your are not inside the sheet, it could occur an error. try to do:

```
with ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SubSheet")
  If UCase$(Range("E30").Value) = "YES" Then
    .Range("E20:I3019").Locked = False
    .Range("E20:I3019").Activate
  Else
    .Range("E20:I3019").Locked = True
  End If
end with
```

Second. You don't return the target range. I mean your `Private Sub WorkBook_SheetChange` waits for a `ByVal Target` as a parameter and your `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` returns any value.It should be a function returning the range or the cell you have selected for me.

EDIT:

```
with ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SubSheet")
  If UCase$(Range("E30").Value) = "YES" Then
    .Range("E20:I3019").Locked = False
  Else
    .Range("E20:I3019").Locked = True
     WorkBook_SheetChange Range("E20:I3019")
  End If
end with
```

And

```
Private Sub WorkBook_SheetChange(ByVal Target as Range)
    If Intersect (Target, Range("$E$19:$I$3000")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "Please select the appropriate dropdown on MAIN Sheet " &    Target.Address
    With Application
       .EnableEvents = False
       .UnDo
       .EnableEvents = True
    End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for you reply. On you first function I get an error on "Activate" line "Activate method of Range class failed". On the Second function, correct me if am wrong I have just changed the function to Private Sub Worksheet_Changes(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range), but its still giving me generic message "Cell or Chart you are trying to change is protected..."

Comment: If you don't use `Select` remove the `Activate`.

Comment: yeah, I have commented the Activate and first function working fine.

Comment: Remove the `ByVal sh as Object` in `Private Sub WorkBook_SheetChange`. Then, remplace `sh.Range("$E$19:$I$3000")` by `Range("$E$19:$I$3000")`. And finally, write `Private Sub WorkBook_SheetChange(Range("E20:I3019"))` after `.Range("E20:I3019").Locked = False`

Comment: I hope those private subs are in the same module...Otherwise try to change private into public. If something helps you could you please, put it useful?

Comment: Definitely, I think we are closer. Both the functions are on different sheet? Do you want me to use on same sheet. I am totally confused with your last comment "And finally, write Private Sub WorkBook_SheetChange(Range("E20:I3019")) after .Range("E20:I3019").Locked = False" ......

Comment: I changed function to Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range). It throwing a prompt now. Unfortunately, its throwing prompt when the cells are unlocked not while its locked/disabled.

Comment: Sorry but I can not help you without any code. Great if it showing the prompt. It is now a problem of logic. Yout just have to change your condition, just call the function when `.Range("E20:I3019").Locked = True` .... I wanted you to call the sub inside the other but you figured out as I understood. If it helped you, could please upvote?

Comment: thank you. I will try to play around. But not sure if its helps me to serve my purpose. Thank you very much for your help!!